# The Simplicial Flabby Resolution of a Sheaf

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

I study sheaf cohomology by [Demailly's book](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf) and I have a trouble. Is the inductive formula at the end of page 198
$$\mathcal{A}^{[q]}=(\mathcal{A}^{[q-1]})^{[0]}$$
right? I think that $(\mathcal{A}^{[0]})^{[0]} = \mathcal{A}^{[0]}$, is it true?

May be

$$\mathcal{A}^{[q]}=(\mathcal{A}^{[q-1]}/\mathcal{A})^{[0]}$$
or
$$\mathcal{A}^{[q]}=(\mathcal{A}^{[q-1]}/\mathcal{A}^{[q-2]})^{[0]}?$$
Is this resolution have any other name?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The explicit expression is indeed
$$\mathcal{A}^{[q]}=(\mathcal{A}^{[q-1]}/\mathcal{A}^{[q-2]})^{[0]}.$$

And the flabby sheaves $\mathcal A^{[q]}$ are also called the Godement sheaves of $\mathcal A$, while the long exact sequence

$$0\longrightarrow \mathcal A\longrightarrow \mathcal A^{[0]}\longrightarrow\cdots\longrightarrow \mathcal A^{[q]}\longrightarrow \mathcal A^{[q+1]}\longrightarrow \cdots$$
is also called the Godement canonical flabby resolution.